# Request timed out in volly class android

Tags: android, http, localhost, android-volley

*local host giving me data in browser as shown in screenshot but Volly class giving me* **'Request timed out.'**

[image: you can see my localhost giving me proper data but doing problem with real device and virtual muchine]

*it was working well in  window 8 but recently i changed my window 8 to 10 so now i am facing this problem but i think it is not happen  with this reason   *

```
   public DataPoint[] getTimeAndU() {

        final DataPoint[] dataPoint = new DataPoint[2000];

        final DataTransmit dataTransmit = new DataTransmit(mContext) {
            @Override
            protected void onCompleted(String json) {
                Log.v("joson",json);
                if (json != null) {
                    //   Toast.makeText(this,"sucess"+json+"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    try {
                        Log.v("testt","dtsfasdf");
                       // JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(json);
                        JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(json);
                        for(int i = 0; i < jo.length(); i++){
                            if (i > 1) {
                                JSONObject obj2 = jo.getJSONObject("a"+i);

                                double x = toDouble(obj2.getString("time_s"));
                                double y = toDouble( obj2.getString("u_mv"));

                                dataPoint[i] = new DataPoint(x,y);
                            }else{
                                dataPoint[i] = new DataPoint(0,0);
                            }

                        }

                    } catch (Throwable t) {
                        Log.e("app", "Could not parse malformed JSON: \"" + String.valueOf(t) + "\"");
                        Log.e("My App", "Could not parse malformed JSON: \"" + json + "\"");
                    }

                }
            }
        };
        //dataTransmit.requestJasonArray("http://192.168.1.12//Rehan/UrbanClout.php?FunctionKey=loginUser&login_name=aaa&login_pass=aaa", "Schedule");


     //   dataTransmit.requestJasonArray("http://192.168.1.8/ahsan_bhai_project/excel_reader/excel_reader/example.php", "Schedule");

        dataTransmit.requestJasonObject("http://192.168.10.32/ahsan_bhai_project/excel_reader/excel_reader/example.php?FunctionKey=time_u","Schedule");


        return dataPoint;
    }
```

*here my services in php*
[image: this is services which is write in php and it works]

Comment: 1. Is your phone connects to the same WiFi network? 2. Make sure the Wifi network is set to a 'private' network, otherwise it will DENY all incoming connection.

Comment: yes my phone and laptop are connected to same wifi

Comment: It may be issue of Windows 10. check [this](https://superuser.com/a/1009111).

Comment: @Rehankhan you can use retry policy

Comment: can you send  me code